# In react why don't index.js files need to be specified on import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Trying to understand while using create react app why if a folder contains an index.js and you want to import it, then you only specify the folder name?

I was curious to know where this is configured to automatically know to look for index.js by default?

This post was linked to a suggested answer but that wasn't completely clear for me.

My understanding is that webpack which I know runs under the hood for create-react-app is configured to by default import index.js - is this correct?
I guess the configuration for this is hidden away when using create-react-app.

Does this just apply to projects built with webpack then?